# Remote Associates Test

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a test that measures a person's creativity, called the `Remote Associates Test`.
When you take this test, you are given 3 words/phrases and have to find a common word that goes with each of them.

**Example**: ROOM / SALTS / BLOOD

**Answer**: BATH

This is because `bathroom`, `bath salts`, and `bloodbath` are all well-known words/phrases.

Your task is to create some questions for this test. You'll be given the 3 well-known words/phrases. And you'll need to tease out the question part.

Note.

- using typescript/javascript
- All three input words/phrases are in all capital letters.
- You can assume that there is a common word among them.

Examples

```
getQuestionPart([“BATHROOM”, ”BATH SALTS”, ”BLOODBATH”]) === [“ROOM”, “SALTS”, ”BLOOD”]
```

Comment: We aren't going to do your homework for you. Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @Mureinik  I really tried, can you help me?
function getQuestionPart(phrases: string[]): string[] {
  const commonLength = phrases[0].length; 
  const questionPart = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < commonLength; i++) {
    const letters = new Set(); 
    for (const phrase of phrases) {
      letters.add(phrase.charAt(i));
    }
    if (letters.size === 1) {
      questionPart.push(phrases[0].charAt(i));
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return questionPart;
}
console.log(getQuestionPart(["BATHROOM", "BATH SALTS", "BLOODBATH"]));